# onClick in table row does not work in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The links work in this example, but the onClick does nothing. When I display the productURL[i] in an alert() it shows the correct URL. Any suggestions?

```
var output='<table class="api-table">';
output+='<thead><tr><th colspan="2">' + productSubstrateName + '</th></tr></thead>';
for (var i=0;i<productURL.length;i++) {
output+='<tr>';
output+='<td style=\"cursor:pointer;\" onClick=\"'+productURL[i]+'\"><a href="'+productURL[i]+'">'+productSubstrateAmounts[i]+'</a></td>';
    output+='<td style=\"cursor:pointer;\" onClick=\"'+productURL[i]+'\"><a href="'+productURL[i]+'">'+productSubstratePrices[i]+'</a></td>';
    output+='</tr>';
}

 output+="</table>";

 $('#'+outputdiv).append(output);
```

Comment: Use inspect element of your browser for this

Comment: What do you expect `onClick` to do, since you're also wrapping the contents with a link?

Answer (score 3):

> but the onClick does nothing.

it does nothing becuase you have done nothing there ..you are just printing the value ..

```
  onClick=\"'+productURL[i]+'\"
        //--^^^^^^^^^^^----
```

if you need to do something then you can call a function there

```
  onClick="myFunction("'+productURL[i]+'")"
```

and your function

```
 function myFunction(obj){
    alert(obj);
 }
```

and you don't have to use `\` there

Comment: That doesn't work also. The strange thing is that the anchor ref. does work, I print the value there also and it goes to the link in the array element when clicking on the link. It's the td onclick that does nothing. The anchor tags are for testing purposes, just to verify that the actual link is valid.

Comment: try this `function myFunction(obj){
    alert(obj);window.location=obj;
 } `

Answer (score 0):

Beginners mistake, thanks bipen, I forgot the document.location.href. :-(

```
        for (var i=0;i<productURL.length;i++) {
            output+='<tr>';
            output+='<td style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="document.location.href=\''+productURL[i]+'\';"><a href="'+productURL[i]+'">'+productSubstrateAmounts[i]+'</a></td>';
            output+='<td style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="document.location.href=\''+productURL[i]+'\';"><a href="'+productURL[i]+'">'+productSubstratePrices[i]+'</a></td>';
            output+='</tr>';
        }
```